# Codeacademy - SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGIje.png)

Comment: Remove that `return`! I don't think you need that! Also returns *have* to be in functions.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Comment: it's telling you *exactly why*. you have a `return` outside the function

Comment: The error message gives you the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a return statement if you are inside a function. The syntax of a function is the following:

```
def functionName():
    # code goes here
    return # you can also specify what to return here or just leave it
    # blank, a return statement is not necessary.
```